# suppress exceptions in twisted

Tags: python, twisted

I writing little customized ftp server and I need to suppress printing exceptions (well, one specific type of exception) to console but I want server to send "550 Requested action not taken: internal server error" or something like that to client.

However, when I catch exception using addErrback(), than I don't see exception in console but client gets OK status..

What could I do?

Answer (score 0):

When you catch an error in errback handler, you should then inspect the type of the Failure and based on internal logic of your application send the Error as an FTP error message to the client
twisted.protocol.ftp.FTP handles this with self.reply(ERROR_CODE, "description")

So your code could look something like this:

```
from twisted.internet import ftp

MY_ERROR = ftp.REQ_ACTN_NOT_TAKEN

def failureCheck(failureInstance):
    #do some magic to establish if we should reply an Error to this failure
    return True

class myFTP(ftp.FTP):
    def myActionX(self):
        magicResult = self.doDeferredMagic()
        magicResult.addCallback(self.onMagicSuccess)
        magicResult.addErrback(self.onFailedMagic)
    def onFailedMagic(self,failureInstance):
        if failureCheck(failureInstance):
            self.reply(MY_ERROR,'Add relevant failure information here')
        else:
            #do whatever other logic here
            pass
```